# Qt 5.7.1 for visual studio 2015 can not detect compiler

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-community

I install Visual studio 2015 community first then I install Qt 5.7.1 for Visual studio 2015 x64. When I check in Toos -> Option -> Build & Run tab compiler, i found that Qt can not detect any compiler? I don't know how to fix it, please give me a piece of advice.

Comment: There are available more downloads by MS: Build Tools - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 and also standalone SDK - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: thank for your rely! But the problem can not be solved, Qt still cannot detect compiler. i got this error
`cl is not an internal or external command`